# iOS Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to construct a View through code. In my init I have this:

```
- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self){
       [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 50)];   
       [self addSubview:[self dateNumberView]];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.dateNumberView);
       [self.dateNumberView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[dateNumberView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse constraint format:  dateNumberView is not a key in the views dictionary. |-[dateNumberView]-|
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 7):

Don't use:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(self.dateNumberView);
```

because the `self.` section is misinterpreted by the system (KVC type navigation). Instead, take a local reference to the view and use it throughout your code:

```
- (id) init{
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
       UIView *dateNumberView = [self dateNumberView];

       [self setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 50)];   
       [self addSubview: dateNumberView];
        NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(dateNumberView);
       [dateNumberView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-[dateNumberView]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:views]];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Using `self.` is just syntactic sugar for calling a method that returns an object, it isn't something you can use as a key.

Try this instead:

```
NSDictionary *views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_dateNumberView);
```

Which should be correct if you are using an autosynthesized property.

Comment: Your response makes sense, however, constraints are created this way in Apple's documentation. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/AutoLayoutinCode/AutoLayoutinCode.html Is this an error?

Comment: @AnthonyMattox Seems like an error. Apple's example code does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use visual format for @property variable
so check the below link, it may help you in your case

[Layout: How to use property in visual format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680525/layout-how-to-use-property-in-visual-format)