# Layout: How to use property in visual format

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have two classes.

Parent class has a property:

```
@interface ParentVC

    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView* logoImageView;
@end
```

So, now, I need to output this view with layout constraints in subclass.

```
@interface ChildVC : ParentVC
@end
```

How to correct format string of visual format?

```
@"V:|-(%i)-[self.logoImageView]" // wrong
```

I found solution:

```
UIView* selfLogoImageView = self.logoImageView;

@"V:|-(%i)-[selfLogoImageView]"
```

But is there any method without new variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Also why is the subview doing the laying-out, rather than the (parent) superview?

Comment: my question about `self.property` accessor from subclass and visual format in layout constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using the visual format language, you are also using `[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:options:metrics:views]`. That method expects a dictionary for the `views:` parameter. Are you using `NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings`? If so, you don’t have to. You can pass in any old dictionary, as long as it maps your views to names that you use in the visual format string. Incidentally, you can also pass a metrics dictionary, instead of what you are doing with the `%i` format specifier.

```
NSDictionary *views = @{ @"logo" : self.logoImageView, // use any name you want here
                         @"label" : self.someLabelView };

// kSomeSpacerConstant is an int or float primitive constant.
// We are wrapping it in @() because this dictionary needs NSNumbers as values.
NSDictionary *metrics = @{ @"spacer" : @(kSomeSpacerConstant) };

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(spacer)-[logo]-[label]"
                                                                  options:0
                                                                  metrics:metrics
                                                                    views:views]];
```

If you don’t want to make a new `NSDictionary` just to hold your metrics or views, just pass in the literal `@{ ... }` syntax for the `metrics:` or `views:` parameters. (But I advise against it for the sake of cleaner code, or if you are building more than one visual format string and you want to reuse the dictionaries.)

Comment: I don't understand the bit about using literal dictionaries. How are they in anyway different from calling `[NSDictionary dictionaryWith...]`?

Comment: `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` was always confusing, because the order of the parameters is `object, key`, there was no internal indication of the difference between an object and a key (you had to remember which was which when both were literal strings), and you had to remember to nil-terminate it. The `@{ key : value }` syntax is very JSON-like, and much easier to read. It is compile-time syntactic sugar introduced in Lion and iOS 5. Read more [here](http://nshipster.com/at-compiler-directives/) and [here](http://nshipster.com/object-subscripting/).

Comment: Yes, I know that, but what I don't understand is why you don't advise its use "for the sake of cleaner code".

Comment: @trojanfoe In above example, there is an additional identifier "views", which gives the dictionary a name (and hopefully semantics to the reader). This can make a big difference in my experience.